# Mock SSL HttpRequest for Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, ssl, https

I'm trying to mock out an SSL HttpRequest but I'm having trouble figuring out how to set the protocol to HTTPS in the request object.  I got started from an example from Phil Haack here:
http://haacked.com/archive/2005/06/11/simulating_httpcontext.aspx

Is there a way to set the request to SSL?

```
public class MockHttpRequest : SimpleWorkerRequest
{
    private string _Host;

    public MockHttpRequest(
        string appVirtualDir, string appPhysicalDir, string page, string query, TextWriter output, string host) :
        base(appVirtualDir, appPhysicalDir, page, query, output)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(host))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Host must be provided.");
        }

        _Host = host;
    }
}

public static class UnitTestingHelper
{
    public static HttpContext CreateMockHttpContext(string host, string page)
    {
        string appVirtualDir = "/";
        string appPhysicalDir = @"C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Workspace\Project\";
        string query = string.Empty;
        TextWriter output = null;

        MockHttpRequest request
            = new MockHttpRequest(appVirtualDir, appPhysicalDir, "default.aspx", query, output, host);

        // How to make the request HTTPS?

        HttpContext context = new HttpContext(request);

        return new HttpContext(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a IsSecureConnection property somewhere in HttpContext.Request that needs to be true.